# Trying to create a range from a set of values

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a range of cells that contains a list of Cell Addresses.

[image]

Column B & C show where a block of information starts and ends.  Column D states whether it is the start of a combination of tables, the end of the combination, or whether it's a single Table.

So basically I am having some difficulty combining the answers from B & C to form a combined range.  So in the picture, Column E shows the start as A170 and the End as A596.  (I don't think this is necessary tbh) I need to make a range containing A170:A543, A548:A554, etc. and it needs to be dynamic.  So these should create themselves based on the values in Column D.  I'm looking to do this in VBA, but if it's easier to do in Excel Formulas, that's okay too.

Can anyone give me some hints how to accomplish this?  My brain is currently mush.

Comment: Combining the regular worksheet cell ranges with the [Union method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213609(v=office.11).aspx) is a small matter but what are you trying to accomplish by combining these with a table's (aka [ListObject object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174247(v=office.11).aspx)) data range?

Comment: On a prior sheet I have a pasted Word Document that has hidden text that shows the beginning and ending of "tables" (the information pasted is in table form, not an actual excel table)  Some of these tables are very similar and can be combined.  I want to combine the information into one group on another sheet.

Comment: That's nice to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a small User Defined Function (aka UDF) that will stitch together the non-contiguous cell ranges from textual representations of their respective addresses. This can return a range for a native worksheet function that uses a cell range like the [SUM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sum-function-0761ed42-45aa-4267-a9fc-a88a058c1a57) or [COUNTA function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/counta-function-47239e46-e523-40f4-94d7-fa2e1711fd4a) (to use two very simple examples).

```
Function makeNoncontiguousRange(startRNGs As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, rUNION As Range

    For Each rng In startRNGs
        If rUNION Is Nothing Then
            Set rUNION = Range(rng.Value2, rng.Offset(0, 1).Value2)
        Else
            Set rUNION = Union(rUNION, Range(rng.Value2, rng.Offset(0, 1).Value2))
        End If
    Next rng

    'Debug.Print rUNION.Address
    Set makeNoncontiguousRange = rUNION
End Function
```

The function could be used on a worksheet like,

```
=SUM(makeNoncontiguousRange(B2:B4))
```

In your data sample this would be like writing,

```
=SUM($A$170:$A$543,$A$548:$A$554,$A$558:$A$566)
```

Note that I am only passing in the start of the range in column B and gaining the end range with .Offset. If you need to expand the functionality to pass in the end range then you will need to check if both the start and end ranges are the same size.